# How can the user know some metadata for an html document

Tags: html

what is the benefit for the `<meta name="author" content="..."/>` and `<meta name ="description" content="..."/>` Or how can a user know these metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<meta name ="description" content="..."/>` tag is used for SEO reasons.
Most search engines use the meta description tag to give the creator a chance to introduce their website. But it also has an impact on the ranking of the website.
Like here:

[image: Description set through meta description tag]

---

The meta author tag, on the other hand, has no impact on the ranking, but can, however, influence the heading, keywords or description meta tags.

Comment: Do you mean that the author and description meta tags are used in search for the document as the keywords meta tag?

Comment: That means that I can search for a site with the author name and site description?

Comment: If the description or author meta tag contains words from your search, a specific page can be found.